# Unable to set up ODBC after installing ODAC (Xcopy)

Tags: oracle, odbc, oracle11g, oracleclient, xcopy

We are trying to use ODAC Xcopy to minimize the footprint of installing Oracle 11g Client.  Currently, we use the Oracle 11g Admin install (~700mb). I've tried using the ODAC Xcopy, and that works. However, the only issue I now have is that I cannot set up an ODBC on the target system by just installing the ODAC Xcopy.

After installing ODAC (Windows XP fyi), I go to Control Panel-->Admin Tools-->Data Sources (ODBC)-->System DSN-->Add-->Microsoft ODBC for Oracle.  I get the following error:

"The Oracle(tm) client and networking components were not found.  These components are supplied by Oracle and are part of the Oracle Version 7.3 (or greater) client software installation.  You will be unable to use this driver until these components have been installed."

I've tried editing the registry and creating the same keys that the Oracle Admin install creates, but still no luck. I'm not sure how to get past this. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using the Oracle Driver instead of the Microsoft ODBC driver?  Microsoft's driver will require the SQLNet drivers which come with your full client install. There should be an additional ODBC driver available after installing the Oracle ODAC. Go to the Drivers tab of the ODBC Adminstrator and you should see something along the lines of "Oracle in OraClient11g_home1" with a version of 11.something. That's the driver you should make your DSN from. I've only used the 10g ODBC install (which could be minimally installed with a selection of "Instant Client").

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you stick to the full installer, which takes care of all the configuration tasks (registry, DLL registrations, etc..), but do a custom install using a response file.

Get the **correct** version of Oracle client installer (not the ODAC) from here:

32-bit:

```
https://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/oracle11g/112010/win32_11gR2_client.zip
```

64-bit:

```
https://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/oracle11g/112010/win64_11gR2_client.zip
```

the Oracle client **bitness** *has to match* your executable's.

Do an **silent** install using this reponse file (edit as needed and save as **client_install.rsp** in the same directory as setup.exe)

[Response file](https://pastebin.com/qniBzrQx)

```
setup.exe" ORACLE_HOME_NAME=OracleClient11201 -waitforcompletion -nowait -silent -responseFile client_install.rsp
```

The key config entry is this:

```
oracle.install.client.customComponents="oracle.rdbms.oci:11.2.0.1.0","oracle.network.client:11.2.0.1.0","oracle.odbc:11.2.0.1.0"
```